# Windows Forms ListBox ItemHeight for first item doesn't work

Tags: c#, listbox, msdn

I'm trying to make a ListBox which holds items of variable size. I got that much to work, as can be seen here:

[image]

But as you can see, the first item seems to be ignored or something. **What's going on here and how I make it also be affected by the ItemHeight property?**
My code looks like this:

```
private void ClassicEvent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    eventCommands.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
    eventCommands.MeasureItem += EventCommands_MeasureItem;
    eventCommands.DrawItem += EventCommands_DrawItem;

    eventCommands.Items.Add("Text: I heard you were going to the Pokémon Centre.");
    eventCommands.Items.Add("if (Has Pokemon (Bulbasaur) in PC)");
    eventCommands.Items.Add("    Text: You have a Bulbasaur.");
    eventCommands.Items.Add("else");
    eventCommands.Items.Add("    Text: You don't have a Bulbasaur.");
    eventCommands.Items.Add("end");
    eventCommands.Items.Add("Text: So be it, then.");
}

private void EventCommands_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(eventCommands.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}

private void EventCommands_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    eventCommands.ItemHeight = 48;
}
```

I *have* tried changing the `e.Bounds` rectangle and also tried changing ItemHeight if the item iterated over was the first one, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What happens if you move `eventCommands.ItemHeight = 48;` before adding the items in `ClassicEvent_Load`?

Comment: That does work, but the issue then is that I can't use it with differing ItemHeight. I just used 48 to see if I could actually get it to work, but it'll depend on the item. I'm guessing something isn't initialized yet for the first call, but I don't know how I'd go about fixing that. I tried calling Refresh(), Update(), and even Invalidate() here and there but no luck.

Comment: When you step through it, does `EventCommands_DrawItem` fire first or `EventCommands_MeasureItem`?

Comment: It looks like it first calls `MeasureItem` 6 times and then `DrawItem` 6 times. And setting the `ItemHeight` property in `DrawItem` doesn't do anything either. I'm guessing it first determines which height an item should have, stores it and *then* draws it. But then I don't understand why it wouldn't work on the first item.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please explain your reasons. I won't learn anything if you don't tell me why you think this is a bad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `EventCommands_MeasureItem`, apparently `MeasureItemEventArgs e` also contains an `ItemHeight` property. Using that *does* work.